# how to work on word and excel from different machines?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I use MS Word and Excel a lot. However, when i'm at work I send copy of my work to email and when i'm at home I download the copy from the email and so forth.

I need a way to make my copies update itself and I can find it from any machine worldwide. I need the way to be secure so no one can edit ot view my files

Comment: DropBox will do that for you

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities.

a) use a **VPN** to connect your home computer to the company network. Put your files onto a network share and access them from that share.

b) use a **Remote desktop** connection and actually work on your company PC. However, remote desktop access across the Internet is frowned upon. You might create a security risk.

c) use a file exchange like **Dropbox** which synchronizes files automatically.

d) use a versioning control system like **SVN** like software developers do.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Microsoft Office, you can save it in **OneDrive** directly from your MS Word or Excel. All you need is a Microsoft account, and a free signing up for OneDrive.

Once you have a Microsoft account:

- Sign in to your MS Office.
- Edit / Write your document
- Click "Save As"
- Save it to your OneDrive
- Now you can open it anywhere by accessing your MS account in the MS Office.

[image: Saving your File to access anywhere]